# Validator on dynamic field works, but the form containing the field is not being updated properly via form.valid

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

Came across this very interesting case while developing a test app.
The task is quite common, form with dynamic field and there is custom validator.
The problem is that while the field validation works fine and validator is being invoked, the form containing this dynamic field is not being updated properly, in particular `<button matButton [disabled]="form.valid">Submit</button>` is not being updated and stays always in 'disabled state'. I am so curious about this coz when I removed my custom validator it worked as supposed.

Here is just a working sample that resembles my case, it has requireHello validator like this:

```
private requireHello(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const selection: any = control.value;
    if (selection != 'Hello') {
      return { requireHello: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

...

```
return this.formBuilder.group({
      unitName: ['', [this.requireHello.bind(that)]],
      qty: [1, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(numberPatern)]],
      unitPrice: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(numberPatern)]],
      unitTotalPrice: [{ value: '', disabled: true }],
    });
```

The full sample with a problem is here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-field-validation-kbyqc4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: just a thought - you probably want to have [disabled]="!form.valid"

Comment: Be sure that you enter a price in each element of the form array: **NOTE**:Use  simply`unitName: ['', [this.requireHello]],`,  it's not necessary the "bind" because your validator **not** depends of another controls or variable of your component

Comment: actually the pattern used in [disabled] doesn't matter that much. the button should react to change of validation status, and it doesn't for some mysterious to me reason

Comment: @Eliseo, it worked.thank you for your comment. i must say that i am surprised to see the reason was using bind(this)

Comment: @VitalyLeskiv, see that your formArray the qty, and unitPrice has validators. The `exampleForm.invalid` happens when any FormControl or any FormControl of the FormArray is invalid (and not disabled). This not change from any version I can remember. The [bind(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is javaScript and makes that, inside the function validator, this was the component, so you can access to all the variables of the component. Should be work :(